# Mergesort (using vectors) and some questions about memory

Tags: c++, mergesort, heap

Back from a long C++ hiatus. I thought to implement mergesort from memory, using containers and not based on CLRS's pseudocode and arrays. The compiles and runs ok on the test cases.

```
/* TODOs
 * Optimizations:
 * [1] Have Mergesort sort values in-place: leftVec and rightVec contains references 
 * 
 * Improvements:
 * [1] Have Mergesort take template arguments, allowing it to sort user classes 
 */

#include "../template/template.h"

// Forward declarations
vector<int> Merge(const vector<int>& leftHalf, const vector<int>& rightHalf, int indentLevel);

vector<int> Mergesort(vector<int>& vals, int clogLevel = 0)
{
   // Base case is vals.size >= 2 
   if (vals.size() <= 1) return vals;

   // Divide vals into two sub-containers: leftHalf, rightHalf
   int r = (vals.size() / 2);
   auto leftHalf = vector<int>(vals.begin(), vals.begin() + r);
   auto rightHalf = vector<int>(vals.begin() + r, vals.end());
   
   // Debug print
   //clog("leftHalf: " + StrItems(leftHalf, false), true, clogLevel);
   //clog("rightHalf: " + StrItems(rightHalf, false), true, clogLevel);

   auto sortedLeft = Mergesort(leftHalf, clogLevel + 1);
   auto sortedRight = Mergesort(rightHalf, clogLevel + 1);
   auto sorted = Merge(sortedLeft, sortedRight, clogLevel);

   //clog("Sorted: " + StrItems(sorted, false), true, clogLevel);
   return sorted; 
}

// Returns a vector containing elements from leftHalf and rightHalf in ascending value
vector<int> Merge(const vector<int>& leftHalf, const vector<int>& rightHalf, int clogLevel = 0)
{
   // If leftHalf is empty, returning an empty (or non-empty) rightHalf is what user would expect
   if (leftHalf.begin() == leftHalf.end()) return rightHalf;
   if (rightHalf.begin() == rightHalf.end()) return leftHalf; // Vice-versa

   //clog("Merging: leftHalf & rightHalf; sizes " + to_string(leftHalf.size()) + "," + to_string(rightHalf.size()), true, clogLevel);
   auto mergedVec = vector<int>();
   
   auto leftItr = leftHalf.begin();
   auto rightItr = rightHalf.begin(); 
   
   while (leftItr != leftHalf.end() && rightItr != rightHalf.end()) {
      if (*leftItr < *rightItr) {
         mergedVec.push_back(*leftItr); 
         leftItr++;
      } else if (*leftItr > *rightItr) {
         mergedVec.push_back(*rightItr);
         rightItr++;
      } else {
         // Both elements are equal: append both elements
         mergedVec.push_back(*leftItr);
         mergedVec.push_back(*rightItr);
         leftItr++;
         rightItr++;
      }
   }

   // If both vectors are exhausted of elements, return
   if (leftItr == leftHalf.end() && rightItr == rightHalf.end())
      return mergedVec;

   // If leftHalf is exhausted, append the rest of elements from rightHalf; vice-versa
   if (leftItr == leftHalf.end())
      mergedVec.insert(mergedVec.end(), rightItr, rightHalf.end());
   else
      mergedVec.insert(mergedVec.end(), leftItr, leftHalf.end());
   
   return mergedVec;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
   vector<int> Test1 {-1, 10, -2, 4, -5, 1, 3, 5};
   cout << "Test1 (before sort): " << StrItems(Test1, true);
   auto Result1 = Mergesort(Test1);
   cout << "Test1 (after sort): " << StrItems(Result1, true);

   vector<int> Test2 {3, -2, 3, 3, 0};
   cout << "Test2: (before sort): " << StrItems(Test2, true);
   auto Result2 = Mergesort(Test2);
   cout << "Test2: (after sort): " << StrItems(Result2, true);

   return 0;
}
```

**Template.h (Boilerplate)**

```
#ifndef TEMPLATE_H
#define TEMPLATE_H

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <array>

using std::string;
using std::to_string;
using std::cout;
using std::vector;
using std::array;

// Returns a string representation of the container as a space-separated concatenation of its
// elements. If newline is true, appends newline to the end of the string. The string is
// preceded by (indentLevel * indentWidth) number of indentChars. 
template <class T>
string StrItems(T container, bool newline = true, int indentLevel = 0, int indentWidth = 2, char indentChar = ' ')
{
   string repr = string(indentWidth * indentLevel, indentChar);
   for (auto it = container.begin(); it != container.end(); it++) {
      repr.append(to_string(*it) + " ");
   }
   if (newline) 
     repr.back() = '\n';
   else 
     repr.erase(repr.end() - 1); // Removes the trailing space  
   return repr;
}

// Console-log. Writes msg to console. If newline is true (default), appends newline to the end of the
// string. The msg is preceded by (indentLevel * indentWidth) number of indentChars.
void clog(const string& msg, bool newline = true, int indentLevel = 0, int indentWidth = 2, char indentChar = ' ')
{
   string indentation = string(indentWidth * indentLevel, indentChar);
   cout << indentation << msg; 
   if (newline) cout << '\n';
}

#endif
```

Comment: Whereas your generic review question is basically on-topic, those specific questions (1-5) are not - to have them answered specifically, you would need to approach a different StackExchange site.

Comment: Questions removed.

Answer (score 3):

### Don't `using std`

...especially in a header. In a source file it's not so bad; but in a header, you're forcing anyone who includes it to pollute their namespace.

### Const references

Since `Mergesort` is not in-place, `vals` should be passed as `const`.

### Make your tests tests

The tests currently in main should have `assert`s so that they act as actual tests.

### Your questions

> By having `Merge` take references to `leftHalf` and `rightHalf`, I'm working with whatever memory was allocated (in this case, stack memory from `Mergesort`) and not *copies* of those vectors right?

You're correct that `Merge` will not make copies at the beginning of the call due to the reference. However, accepting a reference does not guarantee that the referred variable was allocated on the stack, nor should that matter to the function.

> Lastly, I don't need to worry about free-ing  `leftHalf`, `rightHalf`, `sortedLeft`, `sortedRight`, `sorted`, and `mergedVec` because they're allocated on the stack and returned by value, right?

Right(ish). Even if you did need to free the memory, you wouldn't use `free()` - this is C++, so you would use `delete`.

> Is there a way to check which region of memory an object lies in (e.g., stack, heap, global, etc.)?

You should never need to do this outside of maybe a very narrow and non-production debugging or profiling effort.

> we can say the address range 0x4FFFFFFFDDDDDDDD to 0x5000000000000000 is always where a program stores stack frames

Absolutely not, and this is dependent on a number of things, including OS and processor (32-bit vs. 64-bit).

Some operating systems go out of their way to [randomize this range](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization) to make certain exploits more difficult.

Comment: `Don't using std` Good advice in general. It was more for convenience. It's annoying to have to prepend everything with `std::` but I [see](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4NYC-VU-svE) why.

Comment: `Since Mergesort is not in-place, vals should be passed as const`. Fair enough. I didn't have a good reason for making vals `const` but I suppose it's better to be conservative until you have a good reason to keep it non-const (like implementing in-place sorting).

Comment: `The tests currently in main should have asserts so that they act as actual tests.` If I were writing unit tests, I'd look for or write my own method that checks two containers for element-wise equality. I thought it'd be overkill for this example.

Comment: `Right(ish). Even if you did need to free the memory, you wouldn't use free() - this is C++, so you would use delete.` Good catch. Yep -- it's `new/delete` not `malloc/free`. Also, I recently read [SO: Do vectors use stack or heap memory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8036528/3396951) and it seems the container elements are actually created on the heap but the class cleans up itself when it goes out of [scope](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iNuTwvD6ciI).

Comment: `You should never need to do this outside of maybe a very narrow and non-production debugging or profiling effort.` I wanted to use it for educational purposes, not for development reasons.

Answer (score 1):

### Overview

A couple of things I would note:

1: Your code only works for integers. Why do you care? You have shown you know about templates so it would be reasonable to make this sort any type of object that is comparable.

I suppose you acknowledge this in the comments:

```
 // Have Mergesort take template arguments, allowing it to sort user classes
```

But when you try this it will throw up questions around copy (the default and not bad for integers) against move (A better idea for complex/expensive objects).

2: Why only vectors. It is fine to internally use vectors for storage for the intermediate results. But the interface should not limit you to sorting one specific type of container.

Now you could templatize on the container type. But usually in C++ we abstract the container from the algorithm by using iterators. So I would have used iterators as the input to the sort (so that you can use any container simply passing the iterators to the algorithm).

3: You use an "Extra" `2x` the input size of memory compared the input data as temporary storage. You can do this with only `1x` extra memory and with a bit of work you only do the allocation once (doing the allocation again and again can be expensive).

4: You return a new array (with the sorted content). Why not sort the content in place. You don't need to force the creation of a new container. If the original user wants a new container then the user can make a copy and then use a sort in place algorithm. I think the creation of a new container is an extra unnecessary step that you are forcing your user to pay for that they may not want to.

You sort of mention this as an improvement:

```
 // Have Mergesort sort values in-place: leftVec and rightVec contains references
```

But I don't think you can have l/r Vec be references when you do this.

### Comments

> Back from a long C++ hiatus.

Welcome Back.

> I thought to implement mergesort from memory

Its a fun learning example. I like bubble sort my self.

> using containers and not based on CLRS's pseudocode and arrays.

I had to look up what CLRS mean. You learn something new every day.

> The compiles and runs ok on the test cases.

Good. That means you read the rules :-)

### Code review:

If you are not modifying the orignal pass by const reference to catch mistakes.

```
vector<int> Mergesort(vector<int> const& vals, int clogLevel = 0)
                                  ^^^^^
```

---

auto leftHalf = vector(vals.begin(), vals.begin() + r);
auto rightHalf = vector(vals.begin() + r, vals.end());

Worth mentioning this is a copy operation. For anything more complex a move would be better (but that would also require the original be modifiable which suggests a merge sort in place).

Note: There are specific move iterators that you can use.

---

Remove Dead code:

```
   // Debug print
   //clog("leftHalf: " + StrItems(leftHalf, false), true, clogLevel);
   //clog("rightHalf: " + StrItems(rightHalf, false), true, clogLevel);
```

That is what source control is for.

---

How I hate redundant comments.

```
// Returns a vector containing elements from leftHalf and rightHalf in ascending value
```

Don't explain what the code should do. That should be done using self documenting code (function/variable names). Your comments should explain things that are not easy to see be captured by the code (WHY).

The problem is that comments rot over time. So they need to be maintained with the code. If your comments rot to a point where they don't reflect the code which is wrong? What do you fix. So let the code explain how it does it let the comments explain why (or things that are not obvious in the code).

---

Why are you testing the iterators here?

```
   if (leftHalf.begin() == leftHalf.end()) return rightHalf;
   if (rightHalf.begin() == rightHalf.end()) return leftHalf; // Vice-versa
```

I think the more meaningful test is to simply test to see if it is empty.

```
   if (leftHalf.empty())  return rightHalf;
   if (rightHalf.empty()) return leftHalf;
```

I believe that conveys the intent of the code much more clearly.

---

I would simplify this:

```
      if (*leftItr < *rightItr) {
         mergedVec.push_back(*leftItr); 
         leftItr++;
      } else if (*leftItr > *rightItr) {
         mergedVec.push_back(*rightItr);
         rightItr++;
      } else {
         // Both elements are equal: append both elements
         mergedVec.push_back(*leftItr);
         mergedVec.push_back(*rightItr);
         leftItr++;
         rightItr++;
      }


   // Like this:

      if (*leftItr <= *rightItr) {
         mergedVec.push_back(*leftItr); 
         ++leftItr;
      }
      else {
         mergedVec.push_back(*rightItr);
         ++rightItr;
      }

 // PS:
 // prefer pre-increment over post.
 ++rightItr;
```

Most of the time they are equivalent. But now and then the pre-increment is slightly more efficient. Based on the standard way of implementing it.

see: [How to overload the operator++ in two different ways for postfix a++ and prefix ++a?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3846374/14065)

---

Again you are complicating this.

```
   // If both vectors are exhausted of elements, return
   if (leftItr == leftHalf.end() && rightItr == rightHalf.end())
      return mergedVec;

   // If leftHalf is exhausted, append the rest of elements from rightHalf; vice-versa
   if (leftItr == leftHalf.end())
      mergedVec.insert(mergedVec.end(), rightItr, rightHalf.end());
   else
      mergedVec.insert(mergedVec.end(), leftItr, leftHalf.end());


   // Simplify like this:

   mergedVec.insert(mergedVec.end(), rightItr, rightHalf.end());
   mergedVec.insert(mergedVec.end(), leftItr, leftHalf.end());
```

Yes one of those vectors will be empty. But inserting an empty range is not going to have a cost.

---

Tiny bit generic for guards.

```
#ifndef TEMPLATE_H
#define TEMPLATE_H
```

Put your code into your own namespace. Then add your namespace as part of your include guard.

---

Never do this.

```
using std::string;
using std::to_string;
using std::cout;
using std::vector;
using std::array;
```

Its bad in a source file. In a header file you can break other peoples code. Its simpler to just always use the prefix `std::` (its only 5 more characters). Don't be lazy.

---

```
   string repr = string(indentWidth * indentLevel, indentChar);
```

Sure you can build a string using append and addition. But I would personally use a `std::stringstream`. Just like a stream but does it into a string. Nice for building printable objects.

---

A recent addition to the C++ language is range based for:

```
   for (auto it = container.begin(); it != container.end(); it++) {
      repr.append(to_string(*it) + " ");
   }
```

This can be written as:

```
   for(auto const& val: container) {
       repr.append(to_string(val)) + " ");
   }
```

The range based for uses `std::begin()` and `std::end()` on the `container` object and assigns the result of the de-referenced object to the `val`.

```
   for(Type val: container) {
        <CODE>
   }
```

Is syntactically equivalent to:

```
   {
       ContainerType::iterator end  = std::end(container);
       ContainerType::iterator loop = std::begin(container);

       for(;loop != end; ++loop) {
           Type Val = *loop;

           <CODE>
       }
   }
```

---

### Example

I have done a previosu code review on merge sort.

https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/137939/507

At the end of my answer I provide a good implementation.

Comment: `1. Your code only works for integers.` If I knew how to apply templates, I would have done so :-). I thought to improve this code incrementally -- make it work for ints, `git commit`, make it sort in place, `git commit`, make it work for any user types, etc. Copy/move constructors are one of those concepts I haven't learned yet. Will get to it soon, though. [Cherno](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BvR1Pgzzr38) has some good tuts for [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ehMg6zvXuMY).

Comment: `2. I would have used iterators as the input to the sort (so that you can use any container simply passing the iterators to the algorithm).` Good idea. It sounds like this advice goes in tandem with advice #1.

Comment: `make vals const to prevent inadvertently modifying its value.` Fair point.

Comment: `// Returns a vector containing elements from leftHalf and rightHalf in ascending value` Oh common. It wasn't that bad! It was meant to be a brief doc string because I figured just by looking at the signature of `Merge`, it wasn't immediately obvious whether the function returned sorted values in ascending or descending order. I suppose renaming the method `MergeAscending()` or `Merge(bool ascending)` would have been just as clear.

Comment: `Your comments should explain things that are not easy to see be captured by the code (WHY).` I'm familiar with the coding guideline that advocates explaining *why* code does something and not *how* it's done. [Stroustrup](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fX2W3nNjJIo) has a nice note on this @1:01:54. I'd never write a comment that could be ascertained by simply reading the code. However, it's a judgement call -- I've seen functions that read as sentences (i.e., unit test functions), which can look just as bad.

Comment: `I think the more meaningful test is to simply test to see if it is empty.` Agreed `Interator.empty()` is more concise. I just didn't know about it at the time.

Comment: `Yes one of those vectors will be empty. But inserting an empty range is not going to have a cost.` I agree your suggestion is more simple.

Comment: `Its simpler to just always use the prefix std:: (its only 5 more characters). Don't be lazy.` :-( there are trade offs and I think its usage must be accompanied with an understanding of how the code will be used. This isn't going to be production code; it's boilerplate code for small one-off programs used to test C++ features. It kind of annoys me that python has f-strings, C# has string-interpolation, C has printf but C++ is stuck with std::cout << to_string() << std::endl; ...

Comment: `use a std::stringstream. Just like a stream but does it into a string. Nice for building printable objects.` Interesting. Didn't know about stringstream. Will look into some examples, thanks.

Comment: `A recent addition to the C++ language is range based for`. It's a handy feature indeed but in this case, I didn't need to iterate over an entire collection. I needed `leftItr` or `rightItr` to point to the remaining container elements when one (or both gets exhausted).

Comment: `This isn't going to be production code; it's boilerplate code for small one-off programs used to test C++ features` That's a dangerous road to go down. The problem here is the way you normally do things. If you keep doing this as normal then you will inevitably slip and do it in production (that's when things screw up). The best technique is to always treat your code as production code and avoid bad habits that we they don't become part of your muscle memory and slip in where they are not intended. PS/ don't use `std::endl` use `"\n"` (see a lot of other reviews).

Comment: `I needed leftItr or rightItr to point to the remaining container elements`. The beauty of the "range based for" is that it is based on other base level concepts so you can mold its behavior by using simple wrapper types (with a bunch being added to the standard in C++20). You can create a simple wrapper that returns `leftItr and end` very easily. Then create this wrapper object inside the for statement.

Comment: `I suppose renaming the method MergeAscending() or Merge(bool ascending)`. I would not limit yourself to ascending/descending. I would speiify this in terms of a comparator: `template<typename I, typename Comparator> merge(I begin, I end);` Where `Comparator` is a function that compares objects of the type to provide the correct type of sort. Now you can have a default Comparator of `std::less()` to provide your default ascending merge.